# Get content attribute of span by Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have parsed html page: using beautifulsoup

```
authors = soup.find_all("span", itemprop = 'author')
for author in authors:
    print(author)
```

and I got the authors:

```
<span content="Oliver" itemprop="author"></span>
<span content="Jack" itemprop="author"></span>
```

How can I get the content?

I tried:

```
for auther in authors:
    print(author.content)
```

But I get None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the content you should do the following:

```
for auther in authors:
    print(author["content"])
```

Alternatively you can use the following code to store all authors in the `all_authors` variable *(as a list)*:

```
all_authors = [x["content"] for x in authors]
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are close:

```
for author in authors:
    print(author["content"])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are unsure if there are always `content` attributes for the elements with `itemprop = author` you can use AND syntax in the selector to specify must have both attributes before attempting to access:

```
authors = [i['content'] for i in soup.select('[itemprop=author][content]')]
```